# Numbering of section, figures, tables etc with an additional dot

Tags: numbering

I am having an unecessary dot on the numbering of my sections, figures etc, as you can see on the pictures below (i.e., in the figure labeling right before ":"). I would like to know how can this be removed and have a "normal" numbering.
This is the template that I am using:
[template](https://www.overleaf.com/latex/templates/sdq-bachelor-slash-master-thesis-template-at-the-karlsruhe-institute-of-technology/fbncsmwspbgr)

[image: Unecessary dot in figure labeling before ":"]

[image: Unecessary dot in labeling sections]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: I have no idea. The template code makes no changes to the float captions.

Comment: you should provide a small complete document here rather than expecting people to download a template from overleaf. The class file being used will havemost likely  defined `\thesection` etc to end in a .  so you can redefine it with `\renewcommand\thesection{\thechapter.\arabic{section}}` fro example.

Comment: @Mensch - Thanks!;

@DavidCarlisle - thank you for the help, I put the template as there is the .cls and .text files and I thought this could be more complete specially for experienced user that knows where to search. `
Unfortunatly your option did not solve the issue, also I am not able to find where those are being defined (this is why I also put the whole template).
Cheers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `sdqthesis` class is based on `KOMAscript`.

`scrbook` adds an `\autodot` after the last number in sections, subsections, figures, tables, etc.

An easy way to get rid of that annoying extra point everywhere is to redefine `\autodot` to be empty.

If you want to get the point back in the chapter numbering, change the
`\chapterformat`. The same with the page headings.

```
\documentclass[twoside, english]{sdqthesis}
\renewcommand{\autodot}{}% added <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

\renewcommand*{\chapterformat}{% OPTIONAL 
    \mbox{\chapappifchapterprefix{\nobreakspace}\thechapter.\IfUsePrefixLine{}{\enskip}}}

\renewcommand*\chaptermarkformat{\chapappifchapterprefix{\ }%% OPTIONAL 
    \thechapter.\enskip}
```

[image: a]

[image: b]